# Advantages of Bowlegs in Humanoid Species

Tags: evolution, anatomy, bones

[image: Bowlegs]

In an Earth-like planet filled with humanoid creatures (upright, two legs, two arms, head, etc.) the inhabitants have evolved to grow bowlegs.

The question is **why?** What advantage would it bring them?

From what I have read, bow-legs predispose you to arthritis (due to uneven stresses on bones: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genu_varum), as well as make you a bit shorter.

*Note:* This is genu varum - the bones themselves are straight, it is their alignment which is wrong. No bones are curved.

Comment: `bow-legs predispose you to arthritis` - a link would be very much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Riders would benefit - think mongols (nomadic, large steppes, herding, etc)

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi done

Comment: from google apparently the advantage is make them can run faster, "People with bowed legs have knees that whip inward as they step off from one foot to the other. This inward motion of the knees drives them forward and helps them run faster." though i dont know is this the same bow leg you mean or not. also kicking since soccer or football player get this bowleg apparently.

Answer (score 1):

They are tree dwellers. Their knees have the same range of motion as human elbows, if not more, and their feet are able to grasp like a human hand. This allows them to move through tree tops very easily, since their legs are more like arms than actual human legs. However this means their legs are not very good at supporting weight, so they seem bow-legged when standing on level ground.

Answer (score 0):

As Li Jun said,

> "People with bowed legs have knees that whip inward as they step >off from one foot to the other. This inward motion of the knees >drives them forward and helps them run faster."

This is true for humanoid species. However, if you bend their bones backward and change their bones to a more cartilaginous material and you've got legs well suited for jumping from great heights. The flexibility of the legs allows for the species to land without suffering any injuries.

Comment: The flexibility also removes much of the weight-bearing or muscle-anchoring ability of bones, and so negates the two integral functions of legs.

Comment: @XenoDwarf, I agree with your comment. But with sectioned bones in their legs, where the sections would be connected by strong muscular tissue. Theoretically, you. could allow them to control the flexibility of their legs, allowing them to make their more flexible while jumping and less flexible while doing other things.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that they've been using mounts for so long that they've evolved to better fit a saddle than walk well on their own.  And if you weren't interested in having them use mounts, it could just be something that their ancestors did but for whatever reason (technological advancement, social changes, mass extinction of their favourite steed, etc.) they tend not to any more.